# How to use snowsql cli to call Snowflake procedure, (Snowflake-CLI(Snowsql)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to call snowflake procedure in snowsql cli. Any one has tried and able to succeed. I am trying to pass parameters to procedure to deploy artifacts.

Comment: It could be useful if you can share what error you got when trying.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried yourself? If yes, what error did you get?

```
create or replace procedure my_proc(param varchar)
returns string
language javascript
AS
$$
    return "PARAM VALUE: " + PARAM;
$$;
```

Call from SnowSQL:

```
snowsql -q "call ericlin.stack_overflow.my_proc('test');"
* SnowSQL * v1.2.20
Type SQL statements or !help
+-------------------+
| MY_PROC           |
|-------------------|
| PARAM VALUE: test |
+-------------------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.369s
```